# PHP: How to add a variable inside other variable name?

Tags: php, variables

How I can add a variable inside other variable definition?

Here is an example: `$cars_list_ VARIABLE HERE [$car]`

Comment: PHP does support variable variables, but can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?  Generally, there isn't a good reason to use them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. Would a 2D array work?

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve? While PHP does let you do some crazy tricks with variable naming (including dynaming naming) it's generally a very bad idea because there are much better alternatives.

Comment: use an array, in php world, they are like duct tape

Comment: The only credible use variable variables has in PHP is that you can name methods and variables with a sort of uniform matter. This is more important for methods than variables because variables can utilize arrays. You can do stuff like $processor = "Json" and $this->{'_process' . $processor}(). Other than this you should consider a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
${'cars_list_'.$your_variable}[$var]
```

But it is extremely ugly. Use an array instead of multiple variables:

```
$vars_list[$your_variable][$car]
```

Obviously you need to change your existing code for that to work. But it's worth the time/effort.

Comment: I made it with arrays like you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While you could use `${'cars_list_'.$somevar}['car']`, it is an extremely bad idea. Instead, you should have a multi-dimensional array that you can access with `$cars_list[$somevar]['car']`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
${'cars_list_' . 'other_var'} = "stuff";
echo $car_list_other_var;
```

Returns "stuff"